# Doesn't write into NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

I have a app that includes paths need to be added into a NSMutableArray, and the writeToFile it.

```
int r = arc4random() % 100;
int s = arc4random() % 100;
int e = arc4random() % 100;
NSLog(@"%i%i%i.MOV", r, s, e);
NSString * tempFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%i%i.MOV", r, s, e];
NSString * tempFilePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
NSString * documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString * storePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:tempFileName];
NSError *error = nil;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:tempFilePath]
                                        toURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath]
                                        error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
NSLog(@"Old File path : %@", tempFilePath);
NSLog(@"New File path : %@", storePath);
dayCounter ++;
    videoDayCounter = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:dayCounterPath];
    NSLog(@"DayCounter INIT");
[videoDayCounter addObject:dayCounter];
[videoDayCounter writeToFile:dayCounterPath atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"dayCounter wrote to file"); '
allVideos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:allVideosPath];
NSLog(@"AllVideosINIT");
[allVideos addObject:storePath];
NSLog(@"array: %@", allVideos);
[allVideos writeToFile:allVideosPath atomically:YES];
[videoCount setText:[allVideos count]];
[daysLabel setText:[videoDayCounter count]];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[picker release];
```

The NSLog for allVideos is returning NULL.

I tried to create the allVideosPath on app launch by

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *allVideosPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"allVideos.plist"];
 NSString *dayCounterPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dayCount.plist"];
 BOOL booleanAllVideos;
 BOOL booleanDayCounter;
 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

 booleanAllVideos = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:allVideosPath];
 booleanDayCounter= [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dayCounterPath];

 if(booleanAllVideos == NO)
 {
     NSMutableArray *allVideos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
     [allVideos writeToFile:allVideosPath atomically:YES];
 }
 if(booleanDayCounter == NO)
 {
     NSMutableArray *videoDayCounter = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
     [allVideos writeToFile:dayCounterPath atomically:YES];
 }
```

But I guess it doesn't work?

Thank you!

Comment: dayCounterPath doesn't seem to be defined in your first code snippet - are you setting it the same as in viewdidload?

Comment: arm yes? Please tell me what to do?

Comment: What is dayCounter? You increment it with ++ but then add it to your array as if it was an object?

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:tempFilePath]
                                    toURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath]
                                    error:&error];
```

Are you sure that file "tempFilePath" is exists?

Answer (score 0):

In your reading function, is `allVideosPath` defined correctly? I don't see any code setting it in your reading function.